# Rstudio gives an error at startup, Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: r, rstudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chhh1.png)## R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.02.3+492, "Prairie Trillium" (1db809b8, 2022-05-16) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 6.

Error output:

```
dyld[97877]: terminating because inserted dylib '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' could not be loaded: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/dinithfernando/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1+12/Contents/Home/lib/server/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/var/folders/h2/4nllbpkx5511p2hlzlq3mq500000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-BiB1s5/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/dinithfernando/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1+12/Contents/Home/lib/server/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/var/folders/h2/4nllbpkx5511p2hlzlq3mq500000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-BiB1s5/libR.dylib' (no such file)
dyld[97877]: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/dinithfernando/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1+12/Contents/Home/lib/server/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/var/folders/h2/4nllbpkx5511p2hlzlq3mq500000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-BiB1s5/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/dinithfernando/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1+12/Contents/Home/lib/server/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/var/folders/h2/4nllbpkx5511p2hlzlq3mq500000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-BiB1s5/libR.dylib' (no such file)
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*Log File*

```
[No logs available]
```

Comment: What is your R version?

Comment: R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Seems like the issue was with the R package. Eventhough in YouTube videos I watched they installed R which was meant for the apple silicon its not working so I installed R which was for the intel chip now it works. Also in the error image above its saying incompatible architecture so I figured to try out installing the version meant for the intel chip.

Answer (score 0):

From [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-macOS) remove R completely using a Terminal

```
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/local/bin/R /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

then install a fresh copy of R from [rproject](https://www.r-project.org/)
*Note that* there is many R versions to mac os , choose which suitable .

Comment: I removed R using the terminal with ur code and reinstalled R but the issue is still there, the R version that I used is the one compatible for apple silicon. R.app works, the only problem is with RStudio. I did reinstall RStudio too but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you Install Xcode Command-Line Tools

Comment: no I don't use Xcode since its not used in my university. Is it compulsory to install it ?

Comment: not Xcode but `Xcode Command-Line Tools` search for it

Comment: I installed Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.4 but still the error keeps showing up